# Gstreamer pipeline to display camera feed while recording the output to mp4 EOS issues

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, mp4

I am streaming a video feed from PSEye Camera from a Jetson Nano using this pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1" ! nvvidconv ! "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)" ! nvv4l2vp8enc bitrate=1000000 ! queue ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=10.50.26.5 port=5801
```

I am currently receiving the video file on another computer (Windows 10) over the network using this pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5801 ! "application/x-rtp, clock-rate=(int)90000, media=(string)video, encoding-name=VP8" ! rtpvp8depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

I have successfully recorded video to mp4 instead of displaying it with this pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc port=5801 ! "application/x-rtp, clock-rate=(int)90000, media=(string)video, encoding-name=VP8" ! rtpvp8depay ! decodebin ! x264enc bitrate=1024 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

However, when I add a tee that also displays the video, when I Ctrl+C in the command prompt to stop the pipeline, the following message gets displayed and will freeze until I Ctrl+C again:

```
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
EOS on shutdown enabled -- Forcing EOS on the pipeline
```

If I Ctrl+C after, the MP4 file will not get the last frame and becomes corrupted. I am using this pipeline to display the video while recording the MP4 that always gets corrupted:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5801 ! "application/x-rtp, clock-rate=(int)90000, media=(string)video, encoding-name=VP8" ! rtpvp8depay ! decodebin ! tee name = t ! queue ! x264enc bitrate=1024 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4 t. ! queue ! autovideosink -e
```

I have also tried teeing the filesink after the autovideosink, moving the -e to just after the gst-launch-1.0, as well as many other permutations of the above pipeline. I still have problems with getting the MP4 to terminate properly to avoid corrupting the file, but have been successful with displaying the video.

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Answer (score -1):

Had exactly the same problem. My solution was to use other muxer instead of mp4mux. qtmux and avmux_mp4 worked for me.